# Cannot delete item from DynamoDB table (java)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I've been attempting to delete an item from a table in DynamoDB through java code, but every attempt I've made results in the same error:

> com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The provided key element does
>   not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400;
>   Error Code: ValidationException;

My current attempt is very simple and looks like this:

```
final DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(new  AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials));  

Table table =dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);    

DeleteItemSpec itemSpec = new  DeleteItemSpec().withPrimaryKey("cognitoId", cognitoId);  
table.deleteItem(itemSpec);
```

**tablename** is simply the table name, the **credentials** have been verified to be correct, and **cognitoId** is the actual ID of the item I'm trying to delete. The table in question has `cognitoId` as the primary key and I don't understand why the deletion isn't matching the schema. The table also has a sort key, or range key (I'm not sure what it is because the documentation is quite vague). I've been referring to the documentation here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.html#WorkingWithTables.primary.key

Comment: This [delete item using primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455709/how-to-delete-record-using-primarykey-in-dynamodb) should help you solve.

Comment: Try using ```deleteItem(String hashKeyName, Object hashKeyValue)```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you have a sort key while creating a table? If so, then you have to specify the sort key too as you have a composite key on the table. Having a sort key means that you could have multiple records with the same primary key, however the sort key must be unique

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.html#WorkingWithTables.primary.key

The sort key may also be referred to as range or range key in the AWS Dynamo DB documentation and the console.

So your delete item would be like

```
DeleteItemSpec itemSpec = new DeleteItemSpec().withPrimaryKey("cognitoId", "my_id", "sortKeyField", "sort_key_id");
DeleteItemOutcome outcome = table.deleteItem(itemSpec);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "composite key"?

Comment: In DynamoDB, a primary key can either be a single-attribute partition key or a composite partition-sort key

Answer (score 1):

FYI this also happens if you provide the wrong key name, e.g.:

```java
DeleteItemSpec itemSpec = new DeleteItemSpec().withPrimaryKey("#NOPENOTMYKEYLOL", "my_id", "sortKeyField", "sort_key_id");
DeleteItemOutcome outcome = table.deleteItem(itemSpec);
```